# Join sub query in NHibernate (join on multiple columns)

Tags: c#, nhibernate, join

How to express the query

```
    Select * from
        (select name, Max(date) as date from items group by name) as latest
    inner join items as i
        on i.name=latest.name and i.date = latest.date
```

in NHibernate's QueryOver syntax?

As a result I expect to get records with maximum dates for each name from items table.

Each item in table correspond to the `ItemEnity` class:

```
[Class(Table = "items")]
public class ItemEnity
{
    [Id(Name = "Id")]
    [Generator(1, Class = "native")]
    public virtual long Id { get; set; }

    [Property(NotNull = true)]
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }

    [Property(NotNull = true)]
    public virtual DateTime Date { get; set; }

    // other columns ... 
}
```

I've managed to express subquery in a strongly typed form:

```
public class ItemLatest
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
}

// ...

ItemLatest latest = null;

var subquery = QueryOver.Of<ItemEntity>().SelectList(list => list
    .SelectGroup(i => i.Name).WithAlias(() => latest.Name)
    .SelectMax(i => i.Date).WithAlias(() => latest.Date))
    .TransformUsing(Transformers.AliasToBean<ItemLatest>());

var result = subquery.GetExecutableQueryOver(session).List<ItemLatest>();
```

But I have no clue how to write join because I can't find out how to use `JoinQueryOver()` to express connection between two entities (ItemLatest and ItemEnity in my case) that has no relation property referencing from one to another.

Comment: Can't you write it using `Query<T>()` in a Linq syntax? It's under the `NHibernate.Linq` namespace

Comment: Don't know what to pass as an "inner" IEnumerable parameter of the Join() method. In other words, I have only one IQueryable<T> produced by Query<T>()

Answer (score 1):

The JOIN is in the ORM world *(including NHibernate)* defined by mapping. So, if you would like to use criteria and JOIN, it must be over the Referenced property.

What we could for example do, is to create a new object e.g. `ItemEnityMaxDate` and map it to view similar to your SELECT MAX .. GROUP BY. We can extend it like this for example:

```
SELECT main.Id, main.Name, main.Date
  FROM items  main
    INNER JOIN 
    (
      SELECT i.Name, Max(i.Date) AS Date FROM items i GROUP BY i.Name 
    ) AS latest
    ON main.Name = latest.Name AND main.Date = latest.Date
```

The C# `ItemEnityMaxDate` would be similar as `ItemEntity` (well we will need only Id), mapped to the above view.
Then we can use it as a subquery

```
// inner select
var subquery = DetachedCriteria.For<ItemEnityMaxDate>()
    .SetProjection(Projections.Property("Id"));

// the ItemEntity
var query = session.CreateCriteria<ItemEntity>()
    .Add(Subqueries.PropertyIn("Id", subquery));
var list = query.List<ItemEntity>();
```

This is probably not the only way. But this way, having your "special query" represented as an object ... would work

Comment: Do you suggest to create view in DB and then extract it's results to C# object? Because if I would be able to write such a query on NHibernate, I would definitely be able to extract the whole ItemEntity object (by adding more columns to the resulting SELECT clause)

Comment: Not absolutely sure if I understand your comment. But, yes, I thing, that you can create new View in DB and new C# object. Both mapp in NHibernate, as read-only. Use the new ItemEntityMaxDate to filter the ItemEntity.